# Should I use this method?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, session

I want to keep session in a javascript variable that will be a list. Before I am getting data this function.

```
    var twitterData;
$(document).ready(function () {
    debugger;
        if(twitterData==undefined){

            loadTwitterData();

            if(twitterData==undefined)
            {
                alert('null');
            }
            else {
                alert('true');
            }
     }
});
function loadTwitterData() {

    var dataString = JSON.stringify({
        'a' : 'test',
    });
    $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "./ManageData.aspx/GetSessionData",
            data: dataString,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (json) {
            debugger;
            twitterData=json;


            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });
}
```

Then I will create a table using twitterData. Also a lot of functions will use this variable for analysis or statistics. "My session contain twitter follower list of people."
1-Session in the variable is logical ?
2-When i call **loadTwitterData()** in ready function,before it can control **twitterdata is undefined** and then **loadTwitterData()** works. What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to store it via javascript, asp.net offers various ways for persisting data

For Example, the session - Lasts as long as the user is active, plus a timeout period (typically 20 minutes)

```
Session["NameOfYourObject"] = yourObject;
```

Of if you have bigger data you can think about Cache["NameOfYourObject"]

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300437.aspx

Comment: I get the data from /ManageData.aspx/GetSessionData. And this web method return list in session. I just use list in session in jquery.

Comment: Ok, sorry, don't know how to help you with that case